# Datatable - Update attribute data

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, custom-data-attribute

So I have a `DataTable` and I want to update data attribute `data-paiement` on the last `a` of my `td`. Here is an example :

```
<td class="dropdown open">
    <a class="btn btn-default" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/fr/admin/evenements/inscriptions/modifier?URL=noel-des-enfants-2017&amp;id=3440">Modifier</a><br>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-delete-inscription="3440" onclick="DeleteInscription(3440, 'DEMN')">Supprimer</a><br>
        <a class="dropdown-item btnPaiement" href="#" data-update-paiement="3440" data-paiement="1" data-acronym="DEMN">Changer le statut de paiement</a><br>
    </div>
```

So, when I click on it, I call a jQuery function and I send this `data attribute` :

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnPaiement', function () {
    console.log($(this).data('paiement'));
    ChangeStatusPaiement($(this).data('update-paiement'), $(this).data('acronym'), $(this).data('paiement'));
});
```

In `ChangeStatusPaiement`, I update the `data-paiement` like this :

```
$('a[data-update-paiement="' + id + '"]').attr('data-paiement', paye == 1 ? '0' : '1');
```

All is ok, the HTML is updated, so `data-paiement` now equals `0`

But, when I re-click on it, in my `console.log($(this).data('paiement'));` of my jQuery Call, `data-paiement` value is still 1

Is it because the `DataTable` does not update his value ?

Thanks !

Comment: Could you share the whole code in a snippet so we can see it in action? (Use Ctrl+m from the question text editor)

Comment: What do you need more ? This is all the code about my problem, the rest is useless for my bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing jQuery `.data()` function creates an in-memory object containing the element's data attributes values. Using jQuery `.attr()` function to alter attributes values will only update the attribute itself but changes will not be reflected onto the underlying data model handled by jQuery.

**In `ChangeStatusPaiement` you might need to replace:**

```
 $('a[data-update-paiement="' + id + '"]').attr('data-paiement', paye == 1 ? '0' : '1');
```

**with:**

```
 $('a[data-update-paiement="' + id + '"]').data('paiement', paye == 1 ? '0' : '1');
```

A demo here:

```js
let $tester = $('span');

$('div').append($('<p />', {text: 'Accessing data the first time: '+$tester.data('test')}));

$tester.attr('data-test', 2);

$('div').append($('<p />', {text: 'Accessing data twice (after update): '+$tester.data('test')}));

$('div').append($('<p />', {text: 'Nevertheless the attribute has been updated using attr function in the meantime: '+$tester.attr('data-test')}));

$('div').append($('<p />', {text: 'You have to modify via the data function. $("span").data("test", 2)' + ($("span").data('test', 2), '')}));

$('div').append($('<p />', {text: 'Now, accessing the value via "data function will give you the right value:' + ($tester.data('test'))}));

$('div').append($('<p />', {text: 'So use $element.data once "data" function has been called at least once for the element.'}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-test="1"></span>

<div></div>
```